# Converting a String that contains decimal to Long

Tags: java

I have following sample ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/qh3KB)).

```
long lDurationMillis =  0;
lDurationMillis = Long.parseLong("30000.1");
System.out.print("Play Duration:" + lDurationMillis);
```

It throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30000.1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

But why it wont let me convert that number to a string directly ?I can convert number to integer and than convert to double . But is there any other way ?

Comment: Why not convert the decimal directly to a `double` with `Double.parseDouble(text);`  or to a BigDecimal with `new BigDecimal(text);`

Comment: The title says converting string to long, first question is about coverting number to string, next statement about converting number to integer to string. I am confuse

Comment: Not clear what do you mean. You CAN convert any number to `String` with, for instance, `Long.toString(long l)`.

Comment: Long.toString(long l) also gives the same error

Comment: are you aware of the fact that `30000.1` is not a valid long?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The value `30000.1` is an invalid long value. You could parse the double value first:

```
lDurationMillis = (long)Double.parseDouble("30000.1");
```

Comment: I've read that using the `double` data type may lead to precise errors. Couldn't that happen here?

Comment: This may only occur in the fractional part of the number. The integral part will be fine :)

Answer (score 7):

You could use BigDecimal in this case:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("30000.1");
long l = bd.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).longValue();
System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 4):

The title says converting string to long, first question is about coverting number to string, next statement about converting number to integer to string. I am confuse.

But for anything to do with floating points, I have to point you at obligatory reference [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) .

In java, `int` and `long` do not have fractional parts, so a string like `3000.1` cannot be covnerted to one of these. It can be converted to `float` or `double` but if you read the above article you will realize that the coversion can be lossy, i.e. if you canvert that `double` back to a `String` you may not get the original `3000.1` back. It will be something close, for appropriate defintion of close, but may not be same.

If you want to use exact precision then [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is your friend. It will be much slower then the number types, but it will be precise.

Answer (score 2):

Because long can't have fractional part, you could convert it to double and then cast it to long ignoring fractional part

Answer (score 2):

You can do NumberFormat handling as below :

```
long lDurationMillis =  0;
        try{
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            lDurationMillis = nf.parse("30000.1").longValue();
            System.out.print("Play Duration:" + lDurationMillis);
        }catch(ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

```
Play Duration:30000
```