# Converting a string as "1.01" to a Long value

Tags: java, long-integer

We fetch the amount field as "1.01" however we need to pass a Long equivalent of this input to be sent to a third party website.

What is the best way to convert the amount with value "1.01" to its Long equivalent?

I tried using which ends up with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.01"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

```
String amountString = "1.01";
        Long amountLong = Long.valueOf(amountString).longValue();
        System.out.println("Value of amount "+ amountLong);
```

Comment: 1.01 is not a valid long. 1 would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12732309/1501661

Comment: How would *you* define the long equivalent of 1.01? And what about 1.5?

Comment: Sure you don't actually want 101 (1.01 * 100) ?